# Boxstarter or PowerShell command to change "Opens With" properties

Tags: powershell, properties, boxstarter

I'm trying to develop my own [Boxstarter](http://www.boxstarter.org) script for spinning up new machines. I just realized that I'd really like to add a line that will change default applications to open certain file types. For example, I want to open .txt files with Notepad++. I know how to do this by right-click the file and checking it's properties, but is there a line I can add to my Boxstarter script that will do it? Or, since Boxstarter is basically a special set of PowerShell commands, is there a PowerShell command I can invoke directly to change the `opens with` property? I did some searching, and most of the results were about how to get PowerShell to open something, not change the `opens with` property. The rest were all about how to open PowerShell.

Comment: Use powershell to amend registry:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924753/where-does-windows-store-its-open-with-settings

Answer (score 2):

Another similar, but not quite the same, way to go about this is to change the file association you want to associate with a particular applicaition. Chocolatey includes some helper commands to do this and is therefore available to your Boxstarter package. Here is an excerpt from one of my Boxstarter packages:

```
Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation ".txt" "$env:programfiles\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe"
Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation ".dll" "$($Boxstarter.programFiles86)\jetbrains\dotpeek\v1.1\Bin\dotpeek32.exe"
```

So now double clicking on any text file opens sublime or any dll opens dotpeek.

But I agree. Its still helpful to be able to add to the "Open With..." list.

Comment: Wow! That's a lot easier. And from the man himself! I just tried to run it from the Boxstarter Shell and got the error `The Term 'Install-ChocolateyFileAssociation not recognized... CommandNotFoundException`. I'm on version 2.3.24, running as Admin, execution policy unrestricted. Any thoughts as to why the command isn't recognized?

Comment: Oh that is a chocolatey command that will not be automatically available in the boxstarter shell but is in any package install. If you entered 'Import-Module $env:chocolateyinstall\chocolateyinstall\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1' then you could run the command in the shell. When a package is installing, that module is loaded in the installer's session.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Raf for pointing me in the right direction. Here's the code to change the OpensWith property of .txt files:

```
$principal = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\UserChoice",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck]::ReadWriteSubTree,[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::ChangePermissions)
$acl = $key.GetAccessControl()
$right = "SetValue"
$denyrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule($principal,$right,"DENY")
$ret = $acl.RemoveAccessRule($denyrule)
$ret = $key.SetAccessControl($acl)
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\UserChoice -Name ProgId -Value Applications\notepad++.exe
```

Slightly modified from an [answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3a7b4626-1662-4dc9-9a6a-b43af307fb7e/change-file-asociations-via-powershell/#03925747-e23c-4cfc-8802-b0bf87698dc4) in the TechNet forums.

I haven't figured out if there's a boxstarter shortcut for this, but changing the ACL rules was the key. Without it, you don't have the proper access to change this particular registry item. Even when I tried running Powershell as Admin and made sure I had all the right permissions on the UserChoice key (both the administrator account and my user account had Full Control), I kept getting an error that the `Requested registry access is not allowed.`