# Check, if a PDF-Reader is installed - QDesktopServices::openUrl()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

i want to check, if a pdf-reader is installed. The idea was to use `QDesktopServices::openUrl("path/test.pdf")` and if its return "false" i know that no pdf-reader is installed. The problem is, that if a pdf-reader is installed, it opens the pdf. Can I "disable" that?

/edit: My solution:

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.pdf\\OpenWithProgids", QSettings::NativeFormat);
 if (settings.allKeys().size() == 0) {...}
```

Comment: What is pdf-reader? Adobe Acrobat reader?

Comment: QDesktopServices::openURL() calls the standard program that you use for *.pdf files. So it can be AdobeAcrobat reader, but it can also be another program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I "disable" that?

Simple answer - no.

As QDesktopServices::openUrl asks the system to open the file with the associated program, you can't disable it via Qt.

While not recommended, you could disable this on a per-platform basis, but if you're going down that route, I suggest using each platform's own features to check if there is an application associated with the pdf data file.

On Windows, it's in stored in the [registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924753/where-does-windows-store-its-open-with-settings), while OS X uses [LaunchServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html).

However, just because a file association doesn't exist, it doesn't mean that a suitable application isn't installed, for opening a pdf.

If you want to be able to display a pdf, you're probably better off handling that directly in your program. You can read about some options for that [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Handling_PDF).

Comment: Thanks! I now use the registry to solve the problem. I add my solution to my first post.