# show a list of installed applications

Tags: c++, file, associations

When you press the right button in a picture from My Computer , Windows displays a list of installed applications associated with that type of file "OPen with..."
how do I get the same list of programs using the WinAPi and creating a function in C ++ language

Comment: I suggest you search the MSDN site, or perhaps ask there.  Interesting question though.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127438(v=vs.85).aspx) states that "By default, any application registered as a subkey of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications` is presented in the *Open with* dialog box.".

However, two exceptions are listed: A `NoOpenWith` subkey (empty `REG_SZ`)  removes the application from the *Open With* dialog. A `SupportedTypes` key with a list of extensions restricts the application to only matching *Open with* dialogs.

Note that `HKCR` is a virtual hive, formed by merging the relevant parts of `HKCU` and `HKLM`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Open With...' menu is located at the registry key: [`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924753/where-does-windows-store-its-open-with-settings), from there you can [create some functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065/how-to-read-a-value-from-the-windows-registry) to retrieve the data. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a slew of registry functions to get/set values as well as traverse the trees.

As doing this isn't a trivial bit of code (a lot of error checking to be done), and I won't presume to know what your full needs are, I'll leave the implementation to you to try and do first (then come back to SO if you have questions on your implementation).

Hope that can help.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is incorrect. For instance, it misses the equivalent `HKLM` key. I also suspect that this is not a documented/stable API.

Comment: @MSalters `suspect that this is not a documented/stable API` ? What are you referring to exactly? The MSDN API's?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You want an API which is documented in MSDN, but not one for which MSDN says that it will (or might) go away in future Windows versions, or which is marked experimental, etc.