# Make Ruby file executable in Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows, executable

I'm trying to build Tic Tac Toe via Ruby, and I want Ruby file to be executable so everyone can run it.

The problem is: I'm using Windows 10, and I'm not able to make the file executable:

- I've tried to make it executable using Right Click and via the Security tab
- I've also tried following this [guide](https://commandercoriander.net/blog/2013/02/16/making-a-ruby-script-executable/) but didn't work.
- When I'm putting `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` at the top of the file, Rubocop is throwing error telling me that this file is not executable

I've searched everywhere, but couldn't find a solution. I would be thankful if you can help me solve this problem.

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066176/how-can-i-make-a-script-executable-in-windows) of interest.

Comment: I'm trying now to install Ubuntu on my machine. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you, Cary, after moving to Ubuntu terminal I faced another problem which is the carriage return character and I have solved it using GitPod instead of my editor

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to solve this problem. and I'm happy to share the experience with you guys.

- First of all, you should install [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) into your machine.
- Then you should follow this [guide](https://commandercoriander.net/blog/2013/02/16/making-a-ruby-script-executable/) in order to change the mode of your file (to be executable)
- You'll probably after that run into another problem, which is the [Carriage Return Character](https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows). In order to solve this problem, you either install a virtual Linux system into your computer, or you can use [GitPod](https://gitpod.io/) instead of your editor, and that's what I recommend. You can add your project using this link `gitpod.io/github.com/[user_name]/[repo_name]/tree/[branch_name]`
- After that, you should delete your file and create a new one (to get rid of the carriage return character).

**CONGRATULATIONS** You've gotten rid of that problem. Now add, commit and push your changes to the repository.

It's a long journey, but it does what you need.