# Wix3 Open With dialog with period (.) not displaying correctly

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, exe, wix3

When using the following definition for an Open With dialog

```
<ProgId Id="GSA.10.1.Text.document" Description="GSA document (ASCII)" Advertise="no" >
          <Extension Id="GWA" >
            <Verb Id="open" Command="Open with GSA 10.1" Argument='"%1"' Target="[TARGETDIR_Program_Files_Oasys_GSA_10.1]Gsa.exe" />
          </Extension>
</ProgId>
```

I'm expecting the Open With dialog to display `GSA 10.1` but instead displays `GSA` in the right click menu

[image]

And `GSA 10` after selecting `Open With...`

[image: open with dialog with period]

If I change the definition to be `10-1` the first dialog looks better

```
<ProgId Id="GSA.10.1.Text.document" Description="GSA document (ASCII)" Advertise="no" >
          <Extension Id="GWA" >
            <Verb Id="open" Command="Open with GSA 10.1" Argument='"%1"' Target="[TARGETDIR_Program_Files_Oasys_GSA_10.1]Gsa.exe" />
          </Extension>
</ProgId>
```

[image]

But still get the same issue when selecting `Open With...`

[image]

I'm trying to get `GSA 10.1` to display in both menus and I'm having problems finding any documentation about what would be a valid name to display correctly.

Comment: Did you check the actual source code for this? That name might be generating from the exe code?

Comment: Quick link for you: [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration) and one more: [Where does Windows store its “Open With” settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924753/where-does-windows-store-its-open-with-settings).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul The first menu is populated by the verb and the second is populated by the FileDescription in the exe file which I managed to fix. I suppose I can live with the - in the first display